# Implementing basic physics into a simple 2d pygame (inertia and gravity only)

Tags: python, pygame, physics

I am new to pygame and game design overall. I am making a game where a ball follows the cursor. I want the ball to have some physics like inertia and gravity, so that when I fling the ball around it doesn't just make a straight line to the cursor and stop. How do I do this ? ( How do I add inertia and gravity )
My sprite:

```
    class Ball(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, radius=30):
        super(Ball, self).__init__()
        self.height, self.width = 60, 60
        self.surf = pg.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.surf.fill(black)
        self.surf.set_colorkey(black)

        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.center = (self.width//2, self.height//2)

        pg.draw.circle(self.surf, white, self.center, radius)

        # Special varis :

        self.velocity = 0

    def update(self, mousepos):
        if mousepos[0] > self.rect.x:
            self.velocity += 1
        if mousepos[0] < self.rect.x:
            self.velocity -= 1

        self.move(self.velocity)

    def move(self, v):
        self.rect.move_ip(v, 0)

        if self.velocity > 0:
            self.velocity -= 0.1
        else:
            self.velocity += 0.1

        # collision detection for edge of screen

        if self.rect.x + self.width > width:
            self.rect.x = width - self.width
            self.velocity = 0

        elif self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
            self.velocity = 0

        if self.rect.y > height:
            self.rect.y = height

        elif self.rect.y - self.height < 0:
            self.rect.y = self.height
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you please explain a little more about how the ball needs to move please.

Comment: `fling the ball around it doesn't just make a straight line to the cursor and stop` --> https://codemyui.com/stuff-following-mouse-pointer/ | `ball to have some physics like inertia and gravity` (err.. how much gravity?) --> https://howtoconstructdemos.com/physics-ball-attracted-to-mouse-cursor-capx/ | imho, I had failed to understand `a ball follows the cursor` as a goal. If u state something like : `i want the ball to follow the cursor like the ice iced in water following the spoon, (but the view is upsidedown)` or `react like billard ball` is a much better game interface/ux goal.. /(^_^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, when doing any form of `physics`, use vectors, not scalars variables.
This is because `forces`, like gravity are made of 2 components, `Fx` and `Fy` (the `x` component and the `y` component). This also applies to `motion` descriptors, like `velocity` and `acceleration`.

According to your code, your `velocity` is just stored as `1` variable meaning it is a scalar and affects both the `x` and `y` components equally. This is not true... you do not see gravity affecting an object's `x` direction in real life, do you?; (ie, horizontal motion),

rather the `y` direction only; (ie, vertical motion).

Have your velocity as stored in two vars, a `velocityX` and `velocityY`. This will give you more control in which direction the objects move and also which direction certain forces affect your objects (like gravity only affecting the `y` component.), leading to more efficiency and accuracy.

This is effectively the meaning of vectors, when something is described relative to its componential position, direction and magnitude (size).

If you do want to know more, I believe I have already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68668995/13151323).

As for your problem of: *fling the ball around it doesn't just make a straight line to the cursor and stop*:

Look at @p.*phidot* 's comment above.